# How can I catch all the accented characters using regex in order to remove duplicates in my column?

Tags: python, pandas, string, non-ascii-characters, python-unicode

I am working on this French monuments dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17p5o17k1IQiK25Fk8tYMOT-XtrKT6mpn/view?usp=sharing), the `tico` column contains a number of duplicates in French and English.

Some of these duplicates are difficult to catch because they contain accented letters. For example: you might find `maisonduesiècle` and `maisonduesiecle`. These are duplicates, one contains an accented `e` the other doesn't. There are other accented vowels in French such as `ç,é,â,ê,î,ô,û,à,è,ì,ò,ù,ë,ï,ü` that may be present in some but absent in other monument names. How can I filter these duplicates?

Singular and plural forms of the same noun are also to be considered duplicates. For example, `maison` and `maisons` are duplicates.

Some names may also contain typo e.g `maiso2n` is `maison` with a typo.

I have tried to address this by the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
monuments = pd.read_csv("data/liste-des-immeubles-proteges-au-titre-des-monuments-historiques.csv", sep=";")   

name = ''
sieve=[]
for i in range(len(monuments['tico'])):
    for k in range(len(monuments['tico'][i])):
        if monuments['tico'][i][k].isalpha():
            name+=monuments['tico'][i][k].lower()
        else:
            pass
    if (name not in sieve) and (name+'s' not in sieve):
        sieve.append(name)
        name = ''
    else:
        name=''
print(len(sieve))
```

However, I get `25399`, instead of `23874` as the number of unique monuments. `sieve` is a list I created to store the unique monuments. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: The link to the dataset has been updated.

Comment: There is no `tico` column in the linked file. Please double check your example

Comment: Apologies. I have updated the link

Comment: **1st** maybe you need [`strip_accents`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/518232/3439404) (words like `théâtre` vs `théatre` vs `theatre` etc), and **2nd** `if (name not in sieve) and (name+'s' not in sieve)` detects only _overall plurals_  like `maison` and `maisons` and doesn't detect _inner plurals_ like `Maison Renaissance` vs `Maisons Renaissance` (hypothetical examples).